# How to obtain optimally scaled data from homals in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, optimal-scaling

I am using the `homals`-package in R to optimally quantify my data that contains categorical (nominal and ordinal) as well as numerical variables. My goal is to quantify the categorical variables using optimal scaling. To achieve this, I use the rank constraint  `rank = 1`, since this "reduces homogeneity analysis to principal component analysis (with optimal scaling of the variables)". In order to preserve all the information contained in the data I set `ndim` to the number of variables in the data. The categorical variables contain NAs.

How do I obtain the optimally quantified data (rather than the dimensions/principal components) from the results of `homals()`?

Since I am not looking for the principal components, I am not looking for `objscores`. 
I am almost able to extract the desired quantifications, as via `low.rank` I know exactly how each category is transformed. However, these transformations do not include the NAs in the data and I would like to know too how these missing observations were quantified.

From a variety of documentation (Package 'homals' (the package documentation), [Homogeneity Analysis in R: The Package homals](http://preprints.stat.ucla.edu/download.php?paper=525), and [HOMALS](http://mondi.web.elte.hu/spssdoku/algoritmusok/homals.pdf)) I have not been able to figure out how to do this. 
Is anybody familiar with the `homals`-package that knows how to do this or does anybody know how to compute the quantified data from the results?

Comment: I'm not R user and can't speak about homals(), but I doubt that HOMALS analysis quantifies missing data. It doesn't make any kind of imputation, as far as I'm aware. In HOMALS, there exist such a thing as treating missings as "passive data" while computing the components, but is not imputation or quantifying missings.

Comment: I believe you want to use the `opscale` function ([pdf](http://polisci.msu.edu/jacoby/software/optiscale/Jacoby,%20opscale%20MS,%203-26-12.pdf)) from the `optiscale` package. The author specifically mentions how the `homals` and `aspect` packages do compute optimal scales variables, but only in the context of their specific analysis designs. His package should give you the actual values for optimal scaled variables. TBH, I can't figure the package out at all. I created an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49472050/), so if you end up using it please comment there!